Set DatePicker to null when getting ESLint and Prettier errors for null and undefined?
I am trying to give my custom DatePicker an initial value of null/make the date empty. I've tried setting the initial state to both null and undefined, but I get either a ESLint or Prettier error that contradict each other.
This is my DatePicker currently, with initial state as new Date, and no errors:
const [anniversary, setAnniversary] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());

<DatePicker
            value={anniversary}
            onChange={(newValue) => setAnniversary(newValue)}
            renderInputNew={(props) => <Input {...props} />}
          />

When I set initial state to null, I get this error:
const [anniversary, setAnniversary] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());

ESLint: Use `undefined` instead of `null`.(unicorn/ no-null)

When I set initial state to undefined, I get this error:
(Also if I change the type to Date | undefined, or Date | null | undefined, this error persists.)
const [anniversary, setAnniversary] = useState<Date | null>(undefined);
ESLint: Do not use useless `undefined`.(unicorn/ no-useless-undefined)
TS2345: Argument of type undefined is not assignable to parameter of type Date | (() => Date | null) | null

If I change the initial value to nothing, I get this error on the value of DatePicker:
const [anniversary, setAnniversary] = useState<Date | null>();

value={anniversary}
TS2322: Type Date | null | undefined is not assignable to type Date | null
Type undefined is not assignable to type Date | null```

The only way I can set it without an error is if the initial value is a Date object, which I don't want. Any suggestions on a workaround?
